# How to add left join multiple tables in hibernate based on 4th table attributes as join condition

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 4 tables

A,B,C,D

I want to perform the following SQL query:

```
select *
from A
  left join B
    on a.d = b.d
  left Join C
    on c.d = b.d
```

Please suggest how can i achieve it I have mapping in A/B/C for D

```
@Override
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
public D getDObj() {
   return DObj;
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

I have done some tests based on your configuration and this is the HQL query that worked for me:

```
select distinct a 
from A a, B b, C c 
where ((a.d=b.d) or (a.d is null) or (b.d is null)) 
   and ((b.d=c.d) or (b.d is null) or (c.d is null))
```

It supports the join by `D` and is LEFT JOIN friendly.

Comment: This would work like inner join but I want null entries from  B and C if the matching record is not found.

Comment: I tried this select a 
  from A a, B b, C c 
  where ((a.d=b.d) or (a is null)) 
    and ((c.d=b.d) or (b is null)

Comment: any luck with testing?